# How to convert string input into tuple with integers and a string

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

I'm trying to write a function that takes a string provided and turns it into a tuple. For example, given this line:

```
'1/2/3/some text and 5/4=3'
```

I want the output to be this:

```
(1, 2, 3, 'some text and 5/4=3')
```

I know I can use the split function, but I am confused on how to slice it, so the text starting from 'some text' is counted as a string and not separated.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What makes that last `/` different from the rest? Explain it to us as if we're robots.

Comment: In the output or the input?

Comment: @Wintress: In the input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can restrict the amount of splits using the [`maxsplit`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) parameter:

> `str.split([sep[, maxsplit]])`
>   Return a list of the words in the string, using *sep* as the delimiter string. If *maxsplit* is given, at most *maxsplit* splits are done.

You need 3 splits:

```
>>> line = '1/2/3/some text and 5/4=3'
>>> values = line.split('/', 3)
>>> values
['1', '2', '3', 'some text and 5/4=3']
```

To get integers, I would would map a type list to the values:

```
>>> types = [int, int, int, str]
>>> [type(value) for type, value in zip(types, values)]
[1, 2, 3, 'some text and 5/4=3']
```

If the line can't be processed it will be because trying to convert the strings to integers fails. It might also produce lists of fewer than 4 values.

You could wrap it in a `try/except` block:

```
def parse(line):
    values = line.split('/', 3)
    if len(values) < 4:
        return None
    else:
        types = [int, int, int, str]
        try:
            return tuple(type(value) for type, value in zip(types, values))
        except ValueError:
            return None
```

In use:

```
>>> parse('1/2/3/some text and 5/4=3')
(1, 2, 3, 'some text and 5/4=3')

>>> None is parse('12/a/412/3/4/Here is some random text, like 5/4=3')
True
```

Comment: This assumes no strings in the form of `'1/2/3/4/some text and 10/5=2'`. It might be what's needed, or it might not.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 We need a larger test suite.

Comment: It's just the first three values, hence if you were given `12/a/412/3/4/Here is some random text, like 5/4=3`, the program would return `None`.

Comment: Don't you need to cast the numbers into integers?

Comment: Yes, but only if there are three values.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [regular expression](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) like:

```
import re
string = '1/2/3/some text and 5/4=3'
match = re.search(r'(\d*/){3}[A-z,\s]+', string)

if match is not None and match.start() == 0:
     nums = tuple(int(num) for num in string[:match.end()].split('/')[:-1])
     rest = string[string[:match.end()].rfind('/') + 1:]
     result = nums + (rest,)
else:
     result = None
```

Gives:

```
(1, 2, 3, 'some text and 5/4=3')
```

If `string = '1/4/5/2/3/ some text and 5/4=3'` it gives:

```
None
```

Comment: If it is more than three values/numbers, it should return `None`.

Comment: Fixed now. But when the exact number is known beforehand this might be a bit overkill.

Answer (score 0):

```
try:
    result = tuple(int(part) if i < 3 else part for i, part in enumerate(text.split('/', 3)))
    if len(result) < 3:
        result = None
except ValueError:
    result = None
```

`text.split('/', 3)` splits on slashes, but at most 3 times, i.e. into at most 4 parts.

`int(part) if i < 3` tries to parse the first 3 items as integers.  If any of those doesn't look like an integer, `ValueError` is raised, which will cause the result to be `None`.